# I accidentally shorted my RPi and now none of the GPIOs work, is it fixable?

Tags: led

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, and while messing around with a breadboard earlier, I took out a jumper from the breadboard that was connected to the 5V power pin on the RPi and the jumper slipped out of my hand and brushed across some of the other pins on the RPi and the RPi immediately shut off. I unplugged it, gave it a minute, and plugged it back in, and tried using some of the GPIO pins to activate an LED, which did not work. I also tried connecting an LED to the 5V pin with a stronger resistor and that also did not work. The pi still powers up properly and loads raspbian just fine, but again, no gpio pins write out properly. Does this mean the pi is done for? How can i test this myself? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to repair damaged GPIO.

You can check the current state of the GPIO by using the following two tests.  Both tests should be run with nothing connected to the expansion header.

1. the wiringPi library pintest utility.
2. (My) pigpio library [gpiotest](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing) utility.

Both libraries are probably installed by default on Raspbian systems.

Answer (score 0):

You could, but it will probably require replacing one of the surface mounted IC chips on the board and possibly other components. Unless you already own the equipment to do SMD solder rework, PIs are so cheap that you will be way ahead in time and money just buying a new PI.